# Choice element in JSON schema

Tags: json, xsd, jsonschema

I'm wanting to replicate the following XSD in json schema:

```
  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Variable" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="VariableName" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="VariableValue" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ValueMask" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="Prefix" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="RangeStart" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="RangeEnd" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="Suffix" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

this XSD has the following requirements:

- All `Variable` nodes will have the `VariableName` element
- Some `Variable` nodes will have a `VariableValue` element
- `Variable` Nodes that have the `VariableValue` element cannot have the `ValueMask`, `Prefix`, `RangeStart`, `RangeEnd`, and `Suffix` elements
- Some `Variable` nodes will have the `RangeStart` and `RangeEnd` elements
- `Varaible` Nodes that have the `RangeStart` and `RangeEnd` elements may also have the `ValueMask`, `Prefix`, and/or `Suffix` elements.
- `Variable` Nodex that have the `RangeStart` and `RangeEnd` elements cannot have the `VariableValue` element.

I've seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048252/how-to-define-choice-element-in-json-schema-when-elements-are-optional) on here, but it has the `"additionalProperties": false` attribute on it that would prevent the optional use of `ValueMask`, `Prefix`, and/or `Suffix` when opting for option 2.

Does anybody know how to implement these requirements in JSON schema?

Here is the current JSON I am working with: (Please excuse the comments, I know they aren't valid JSON)

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "variableName": {
      "type": "string"
    },

    //this
    "variableValue": {
      "type": "string"
    },

    //or that
    "valueMask": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "prefix": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "rangeStart": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "rangeEnd": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "suffix": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've dont additional research and found this quesiton: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50881764/mutually-exclusive-combinations-of-properties However it violates the DRY principal. If this ends up being the case then I will open an issue on the github issue tracker.

Comment: All the techniques you need to solve this can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required